# The option "Recall this message" is unavailable in my Outlook 2016

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

I'm looking for the option "Recall this message" that let the user recall his message in outlook 2016. However, I didn't find it anywhere.
It should be there:

[image: Recall this message]

This is from my laptop:

[image: Issue]

I tried to look at the Quick Access Toolbar without any results:

[image]

PS: I'm using a Microsoft Exchange account.

Comment: Double-click to the open the e-mail in its own window. Go to File, and you should see a Message Resend and Recall. You can only recall if you're sending to another Exchange server I believe.

Comment: Are you connecting to an Exchange server? Who is your mail provider? How are you connecting to said mail provider? Exchange? IMAP? POP3?

Comment: @sun sorry I forgot to mention that i'm using a microsoft exchnage account

Comment: who manages your exchange server?  it could be that option is disabled at the server (since most of the time it is rather useless).

Comment: The company i'm working for :p

Comment: Is this your e-mail account or one you share as a resource, or belongs to someone else? "You cannot recall messages sent through shared accounts." https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/email/recalling-sent-messages/  You should update your original post to include more details as it is important to troubleshoot.

Comment: @Sun No it's my own account

Comment: this is pc outlook and not mac outlook, correct? mac outlook doesn't have recall feature. you can try creating a new profile and see if that option appears... could be some sort of profile corruption: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/829918

Comment: Sorry I'm out of ideas. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to Send Items
2. Find the email & double click on the email to open it in a separate window
3. In the **Move** tab click on **Actions** > Recall this message